# Creating a View with an uniqueidentifier column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to take the data from a table in the Database, in my case dbo.EventsCollage and create a View for it.

The View should contain all the records for table to which is based plus I should add a Column called Id of `datatype uniqueidentifier`.

A uniqueidentifier value (random generated) should be created automatically for every records display in the View

Here how I am creating the View

```
CREATE VIEW testView
AS
SELECT
x.Name
FROM dbo.EventsCollage as x;
```

Could you please point me out a sample of code?

Comment: Do you need that value to be repeatable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `newId()` . (***Note: this will give you a new Id for each row each time you select***)

```
CREATE VIEW testView
AS
SELECT
newId() Id, x.Name
FROM dbo.EventsCollage as x;
```

([DEMO - 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/269e1/3))

Or if you need each row having same uniqueidentifier everytime, try (***Note: this will work only up to 100mil records***)

```
CREATE VIEW testView
AS

SELECT convert(uniqueidentifier,
       stuff('62799568-6EF2-4C95-84E7-4953A6959C99',1,len(rn),convert(varchar,rn))) id,
       T.Name
FROM ( 
  select x.Name,  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by x.Name) rn
FROM dbo.EventsCollage as x ) T;
```

([DEMO - 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/269e1/1))

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into using `NEWID()`:

```
CREATE VIEW testView
AS
SELECT
x.Name, NEWID() as youruniquecol
FROM dbo.EventsCollage as x;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7642f/1).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY col1 ) AS id, col1, col2, col3
FROM MyResults
```

See:
[Add Identity column to a view in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382287/add-identity-column-to-a-view-in-sql-server-2008)